# Javascript extract object names to an array

Tags: javascript

How do I get object names to an array in JavaScript?

```
{
    "Ford F-150": [
        {
            "year": 2007,
            "model": "Ford F-150"
        },
        {
            "year": 2007,
            "model": "Ford F-150"
        },
        {
            "year": 2007,
            "model": "Ford F-150"
        }
    ],
    "Toyota Camry": [
        {
            "year": 2011,
            "model": "Toyota Camry"
        }
    ],
    "Dodge RAM": [
        {
            "year": 2005,
            "model": "Dodge RAM"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect the result like

```
var result = ["Ford F-150", "Toyota Camry", "Dodge RAM"]
```

Comment: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) should do

Answer (score 0):

Use this property to access the keys of your object

```
Object.keys(your_obj);
```